# Splitting horizontally in 2 frames in beamer

Tags: beamer, minipage, split

I want to split horizontally a frame into two different parts. See my example enclosed.
I assume I have to use minipage but I do not see how. Thank you !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, here is a first proposal. I will be happy to improve it based on your feedback.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item blablabla
            \item test01
            \item test02
        \end{itemize}
        \hrule
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Here is an improved and reusable version.
This new code is based on the `xparse` package which allows to define a custom environment with versatile capabilities.
The dimension of the `itemize` area is fixed using a `minipage` (thanks @samcarter for the tip). You can of course modify all sizes.

```
% arara: lwpdflatex
\documentclass{beamer}
% New environment definition using the xparse package (already loaded by beamer)
% The environment has a mandatory argument for the image and the content enclosed in the \begin{} ... \end{} pair. 
% The height of the itemize area is fixed using a minipage environment and is fixed at 3cm
% The image has a fixed maximum height of 4cm and a fixed maximum width of \textwidth, the aspect ratio is maintained.
\NewDocumentEnvironment{itemizewithimage}{ m b }{%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}%
        #2
    \end{itemize}%
\end{minipage}
\vfill%
\hrule
\begin{center}%
    \includegraphics[height=4cm,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{#1}%
\end{center}%
}{%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemizewithimage}{example-image-a}
            \item blablabla
            \item test01
            \item test02
        \end{itemizewithimage}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is almost what I have been looking for. What I would like is if I only have 2 items in the itemize, I want the figure to stay at the same place. Do you know if it is possible to do it?

Comment: Just to be clear : you want to be able to use this format multiple times ? What should be the image dimensions ? And of course it is possible :)

Comment: Yes. What I want is to for instance have 3 items in the itemize and the figure A then on the next slide, have 2 items in the itemize and the figure B, where the figure B has the same dimension and the same position than the figure A. I do not want the position of the figure to be affected by the text above (the itemize in our case).

Comment: @Akusa, sorry for the delay, I just updated my answer. See if it helps.

Comment: Once again, what is the reason for the downvote ???

Comment: Thank you very much. No idea, the downvote is not coming from me.